# Run Matlab GUI through ssh?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, ssh

I am trying to run the MATLAB through ssh on a remote cluster. When i type matlab in the terminal it just opens the MATLAB command line in the terminal environment. My question is there any way that i can have access to the MATLAB GUI as well?

Comment: Not really programming related, however if you have X installed and the DISPLAY environment variable set correctly on your local machine and use `ssh -Y <hostname>` it _should_ just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get the GUI to show up. You need (i) an X-windows system running on your local machine and (ii) to use the -X option for ssh to enable X11 forwarding. More detailed answer:

1. From your local terminal, check the the DISPLAY environmental variable is set. Eg. from the terminal on my mac:`echo $DISPLAY` returns `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.y9pXfRNnTu/org.macosforge.xquartz:0` If DISPLAY environmental variable isn't set, you probably need to get an X-server properly installed (eg. for Mac OS X it is X11.app).
2. When you login to the remote machine using ssh, use the -X option to enable X11 forwarding. Eg. from your local terminal type: `ssh -X username@remotehost.com` where username and remotehost are your username and the remote host name respectively. With the -X option, SSH will make it all magically work: ssh will set the DISPLAY environmental variable on the remote machine to a port ssh is listening to and channel the graphics data back to back to the address in your local DISPLAY environmental variable, which should point to your local X-server.

---

Btw, unless you're RIGHT next to the cluster networking wise, this is likely to be !@#$!@#$ slow & annoying. If you're a student, I'd highly recommend ponying up and getting a student edition of Matlab so you can run the GUI locally. Student version isn't that expensive.

Comment: MATLAB student version is $50...my daughter bought one for school last year.  It comes with lots of toolboxes as well.  http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_version/add-ons.html?s_tid=ac_add_sv_bod#suite-add-ons

Comment: Thank you for that, actually i have access to a academic version of matlab on my computer. The only reason for working on cluster is it is faster than my machine as my codes are parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

You can not only with SSH. You may be interested in [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). But, do you absolutely need a GUI?

Moreover, what about using MATLAB on your own computer? If it is a license problem, you should give a try to [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) that is free/libre, gratis and cross-platform.

Comment: Not true. Matlab could run on console.